# copy range and send as outlook email body

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below VBA code to copy range in excel and send it as body of the email from outlook. The excel sheet is saved in server and it works perfectly fine in my computer and some other computers/laptops too. But it gives compile error for some other users. All users are connected to same network and using same version of outlook and excel 2016.

> Compile error - Can't find project or Library

The error comes at line mentioned as (ERROR HERE) when I click the command button running this script from other computers of my colleagues(users). Outlook and excel are 2016. I have added the outlook object library in the reference menu. Excel sheet is located on server folder `\\hp-fs2\Groups\H&P ISM\Navigational Assessment` 
Any solution for amending the code from the experts on this forum would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Sheet1.Unprotect ("so")
Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9:I22").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "abcdg@abcd.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "This is Automatic Notification - Navigation Assessment Overview sheet has just been updated !"
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    '.Send
    .display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

Sheet1.Protect ("so")
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'( ERROR HERE - at the line TempFile = Environ$ )

rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I think you might struggle if you can't add the Outlook reference tbh

Comment: Add the Outlook object model type library reference to your project, work with the early-bound goodness (keep it to yourself!), and don't use any constant defined in that library (declare & use your own copies instead); then when it works, remove the reference and change the declarations from `Outlook.Something` back to `Object`, and nobody will ever notice you built it with early-bound references. "Runtime error" is rather surprising though. Are you sure there's no error number associated with the error? 438? And a more meaningful error message? What line is throwing the error?

Comment: @Mat'sMug - Sorry late response, was sick.  The compile error " Can't find project or Library" comes at the line mentioned below.    `TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm" `. But it does not give error in my computer and in some of my colleagues laptop connected to network. It only gives this error on some people who are also connected to same network. All of us are working on local PCs and laptops connected to one network. This excel sheet is located in path `\\hp-fs2\Groups\H&P ISM\Nav_Audit`

Comment: @Mat'sMug - I have also added the Outlook reference now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in the temp file... perhaps the other users don't have the appropriate credentials to save to Environ$ on their computers?  Or does Environ$ point to some restricted network location?

I bet that if you make the temp file happen at the user's computer under My Documents\yourproject\temp  (or some equivalent) that this problem will go away.